# Is this definition of a derivative correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

let $v(x,h)$ that: $v(x,0)=0$

$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+v(x,h)$

obviously we need the right side to be independent of h, so $v(x,h)$ must cancel some $h$.

Comment: Are you missing $\lim_{h\to 0}$ on the RHS? Or does $v(x,h)$ represent the higher order terms?

Comment: $v$ is not independent of $h,$ you need the condition $\lim_{h\to0} v(x,h)=0.$ It is unclear what you mean by “cancel.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $v$ is dependent of $h$. RHS needs to be independent.

Comment: Technically, it cancels because $v$ is defined as $$v(x,h)=f’(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ But this can’t be a definition of $f’(x).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $v$ is defined that: $$v(x,0)=0$$

Comment: This equation is not generally used as a definition for the derivative $f'$.

Comment: Well, we don’t really care what $v(x,0)$ is, but we require $\lim_{h\to0} v(x,h)=0.$ If we define $v(x,h)$ at $h=0,$ we want it to be continuous in $h,$ then we must define $v(x,0)=0.$

Comment: @mvw This approach is related to how we define derivatives of $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n.$ There. If $T$ is a matrix we say $T$ is the derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf x$ if $$u(\mathbf x,\mathbf h)=f(\mathbf  x+\mathbf h)-f(\mathbf x)-T\mathbf x$$ satisfies $\frac{u(\mathbf x,\mathbf h)}{|h|}\to 0$ as $\mathbf h\to 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok, this is the reason why i asked. do you know of the $v(x,h)$ that would refute above definition?

Comment: One usually requires $v(x,h) = O(h)$.

Comment: @thomas you can not divide vectors meaningful, so the given form is pointless.

Comment: The above isn’t a complete definition. $v(x,0)=0$ does you nothing if $v$ is not continuous at $h=0.$  Given any  $f(x)$    your definition would let us define, for any value $C$: $$v(x,h)=\begin{cases}C-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&x\neq0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$ You need continuity at $h=0$ to ensure that $C$ is the derivative.

Comment: I would suggest to end the discussion. It is too tiresome to turn it into a good question.

Comment: it is not a discussion. i asked if this definition is valid or not. you say no?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok so it need to be continuous, and then it work?

Comment: Yes, then the definiti9n is fine.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you

Comment: It is not necessary that $v(x,0)$ is defined. Only $\lim_{h\to0} v(x,h)$ needs to be defined for $f'(x)$ to be defined.